# Indefinite integral of $\log(\sin(x))$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm computing the indefinite integral of $\log(\sin(x))$; this is the my solution with integration by substitution:

$$
\begin{align}
&\int\log(\sin(x))dx\\
= &\int\log(y)\frac{1}{\cos(x)}dy \\
= &\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\int\log(y)dy \\
= &\frac{1}{\cos(x)}(y\log(y)-y) \\
= &\tan(x)\log(\sin(x))-\tan(x)
\end{align}
$$

Because I did the substitution $y=\sin(x), dy=\cos(x)dx\rightarrow dx=\frac{dy}{\cos(x)}$.

Wolfram online gives a different result; where is the my error?

Comment: The $\;\frac1{\cos x}\;$ is *actually* a function of the new variable $\;y\;$ : you can't take it out of the integral.

Comment: This does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: You can not take $\cos x$ out of the integral and you have to transform $\cos x$ by putting $x=\sin^{-1}y$ there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\cos(x)$ is not a constant, because $x$ depends on $y$, so you can't pull $\cos(x)$ out of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

As Cameron said, this indefinite integral is not elementary.  Maple does it in terms of a dilogarithm...
$$
\int \ln  \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) \,{dx}=
-x\ln  \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{2\,ix}} \right) +x\ln  \left( \sin \left( x
 \right)  \right) +\frac{i{x}^{2}}{2}+\frac{i\,{\rm Li_2} \left( {{\rm e}
^{2\,ix}} \right)}{2}
$$