# Integration of log(sin(x))

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Can anyone please help me the following indefinite integral:

$$\int \log(\sin(x))dx$$

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried computer algebra systems?

Comment: @Semiclassical All answers there compute a definite integral.

Comment: We have an answer from Maple [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450538/indefinite-integral-of-log-sinx), though.

Comment: @neil: I just posted a [closed form solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x) for the integral. Do not worry about the downvote.